# нахождение последовательности в числе пи

Tags: математика

дана последовательность из 10 символов, как я могу рассчитывать номер позиции с которой начинается эта последовательность в числе PI

пример

```
--0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
3,1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 8  9  7  9  3  2  3  8  4  6  2
```

моя последовательность 65358
я хочу получить номер позиции - 6
какую формулу применять?
(без математики программа получается очень медленной. если последовательность очень далеко)

Comment: Переведите число пи и свое число в строку. Дальше задача решается просто.

Comment: Видели такой ресурс? - http://www.angio.net/pi/ там эта задача вполне успешно решается до 200 миллионов цифр. Я не читал, но там есть страница с объяснениями того, как это работает у них: http://www.angio.net/pi/how.html

Comment: Скачайте строку с числом Пи откуда-нибудь (например вот тут миллион знаков - https://www.angio.net/pi/digits.html) и выполняйте по ней текстовый поиск.

Comment: Уточните что вы имеете вииду под "без математики программа получается очень медленной"?

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку у числа Пи нет никакой закономерности в знаках (по крайней мере так утверждается), никакая математика вас не спасет.

Поможет только предвычисление и поиск. Если заранее получить строку десятичных цифр, то поиск подстроки можно ускорить, воспользовавшись более быстрыми алгоритмами поиска подстрок, типа Кнута-Морриса-Пратта или Бойера-Мура (надеюсь, в фамилиях сделал не слишком много ошибок :))

Если Пи задано в другом формате - надо смотреть, что тут может помочь. Но в любом случае без предвычисления и поиска - того или иного - по-моему, не обойтись.

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте строку с числом Пи откуда-нибудь (например вот тут миллион знаков - https://www.angio.net/pi/digits.html) и выполняйте по ней текстовый поиск.